# Spring web app not deploying after reverse engineering

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, netbeans

My **Web Application** build from **Spring 3.X + Hibernate 3.X + MySql with maven** using **NetBeans 8.0.2**

In 8.0.2 of NetBeans Reverse Engineering works slowly but after successfully completed reverse engineering, also successfully clean and build main project

But, while i am deploying Web Application there are some errors which is described below.

My application build in modular manner using maven as Build automation tool and its working and deployed fine before Hibernate reverse Engineering performed

this is working perfectly in netbeans 7.X.x

I am very confused because there is not any problem in my code or not any problem in reverse engineering But, problem is in Deploying Web Application after Reverse Engineering in NetBeans 8.0.2

**Error Message:**

```
02-Sep-2015 10:59:08.449 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-11] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing log4j from [classpath:com/bul/etender/property/log4j.properties]
02-Sep-2015 10:59:08.516 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-11] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Shutting down log4j
02-Sep-2015 10:59:08.517 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-11] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
02-Sep-2015 10:59:28.740 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
02-Sep-2015 10:59:28.787 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
02-Sep-2015 10:59:52.885 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dashboardController1' defined in class path resource [com/bul/etender/spring/xml/controller/BeanController.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userActivityLogService1' while setting bean property 'userActivityLogService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userActivityLogService1' defined in class path resource [com/bul/etender/spring/xml/service/BeanService.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userActivityLogDAO1' while setting bean property 'userActivityLogDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userActivityLogDAO1' defined in class path resource [com/bul/etender/spring/xml/dao/BeanDAO.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDAOSupportMaster1' while setting bean property 'hibernateDAOSupportMaster'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDAOSupportMaster1' defined in class path resource [com/bul/etender/spring/xml/util/BeanUtil.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory1' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory1' defined in class path resource [com/bul/etender/spring/xml/Hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4760)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5184)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:455)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1496)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1437)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:884)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:335)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userActivityLogService1' defined in class path resource [com/bul/etender/spring/xml/service/BeanService.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userActivityLogDAO1' while setting bean property 'userActivityLogDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userActivityLogDAO1' defined in class path resource [com/bul/etender/spring/xml/dao/BeanDAO.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDAOSupportMaster1' while setting bean property 'hibernateDAOSupportMaster'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDAOSupportMaster1' defined in class path resource [com/bul/etender/spring/xml/util/BeanUtil.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory1' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory1' defined in class path resource [com/bul/etender/spring/xml/Hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 61 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userActivityLogDAO1' defined in class path resource [com/bul/etender/spring/xml/dao/BeanDAO.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDAOSupportMaster1' while setting bean property 'hibernateDAOSupportMaster'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDAOSupportMaster1' defined in class path resource [com/bul/etender/spring/xml/util/BeanUtil.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory1' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory1' defined in class path resource [com/bul/etender/spring/xml/Hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 71 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDAOSupportMaster1' defined in class path resource [com/bul/etender/spring/xml/util/BeanUtil.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory1' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory1' defined in class path resource [com/bul/etender/spring/xml/Hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 81 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory1' defined in class path resource [com/bul/etender/spring/xml/Hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 91 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:508)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:684)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
... 98 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Connection timed out: connect Nested exception: Connection timed out: connect
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:499)
... 102 more
```

here is **hibernate.config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.165:3306/eproc_repo?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
<mapping resource="com/bul/etender/model/VendorAuctionEmdRfpReverseService.hbm.xml"/>
  .
  .
  .
  .
    <mapping resource="com/bul/etender/model/CountryT.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is **ApplicationContex.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

<!-- Common Declaration -->
<import resource="Common.xml" />

<!-- other bean Declaration -->
<import resource="controller/BeanController.xml" />
<import resource="service/BeanService.xml" />
<import resource="dao/BeanDAO.xml" />
<import resource="model/BeanModel.xml" />
<import resource="report/BeanReport.xml" />
<import resource="validator/BeanValidator.xml" />
<import resource="util/BeanUtil.xml" />

<!-- Transaction Declaration -->
<import resource="Transaction.xml" />

<!-- Database Configuration -->
<import resource="DataSource.xml" />
<import resource="Hibernate.xml" />

<!-- View Resolver Declaration -->
<import resource="ViewResolver.xml" />

<!-- Locale Resolver Declaration -->
<import resource="LocaleResolver.xml" />

<!-- Theme Resolver Declaration -->
<import resource="ThemeResolver.xml" />

<!-- Spring Scheduler Declaration -->
<import resource="Scheduler.xml" />

</beans>
```

Here is **Hibernate.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory0"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_catalog">${jdbc.database}</prop>
            <!--<prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${jdbc.schema}</prop>-->

            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
           </props>
    </property>

    <property name="mappingLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:com/bul/etender/model/*.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory1"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" parent="sessionFactory0">
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory2"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" parent="sessionFactory0">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource2" />
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Please share your configuration XML

Comment: As per your error we can see that your application is not able to create the required bean from the provided `XML`, so please check the package path provided in the `XML` configuration for the dependency injection.